# Create a query based on populated combo box of tables

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a database that is simply collecting a bunch of other unrelated linked tables, querying each of them and then finally creating a union query.

In order to speed up the process, I want to create a form that will allow the user to first autolink the table, a query will pull the list of tables which will then be selectable in a drop down menu via a combobox.

Now, the next part of the code should automatically create a query based on whatever is selected in the combobox but I'm not sure how to do that. IE:

```
Dim var1 As Object

Dim qdf As QueryDef

Dim sql As String

Dim db As Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    Set var1 = Me.Combo3

    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("newQuery1", "SELECT * FROM var1")
```

What ends up happening is that it creates the table called "Var1" which obviously doesn't exist. I want it instead to create a query of the same name of whatever table was selected from the dropdown I think this is a pretty basic question but I'm very new to Access/VBA.

Comment: I've never done what you're trying to do, but you are not using the variable `var1` like you think you are. You are explicitly saying SELECT * FROM Var1. **NOT** SELECT * FROM myVariable. If this is possible, you would need to concatenate your variable into your SQL string. Like this: `SELECT * FROM '" & var1 & "'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like all you are needing is:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("newQuery1", "SELECT * FROM [" & Me.Combo3 & "]")
```

If you are wanting to create a query with the name of the query as the table name:

```
Dim qdf As QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef(Me.Combo3, "SELECT * FROM [" & Me.Combo3 & "]")
```

However you will get an error, because you can't have a table and query named the same.

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thank you! The syntax was definitely off and it looks like I have some more reading to do for the SQL VBA portion. Appreciate it.